# table strips columns with hidden columns

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with hidden columns. at first, i want the table columns to be painted as strips. when i expand the table (so hidden columns will be shown) i want their color to be as the 'primary' color (the ones that wasn't hidden at first).
I can't use css `nth-of-type(odd)` because the primary columns will not always be order in even/odd.

I'm building this table with jQuery after i get an ajax response so i have control on which cell i'm creating (primary or hidden).

i can't figure a way to make this work[image]

Comment: can you post your code, or preferably a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Will there only be one set of hidden columns or can hidden columns be revealed multiple times?

Comment: In your jquery, add a class even to the primary columns that are even, and a class odd to the odd primary columns. There is no pure CSS solution, AFAIK

Comment: @vals my problem is the hidden ones. the hidden columns (could be more then one next to each other) should be the same as the primary column next to them

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 i didn't listen to no one. i tried it my self and td:nth-child(odd) solution will no work.

Comment: like i said, post some code or a fiddle.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

First you stripe the primary columns on your document.load. P is your primary column td's class and H is your hidden column's td class, and gray is that styling you want to apply.

```
$("tr td.P:even").each(function (index, element) {
     $(element).addClass("gray")
})
```

Then after you unhide your hidden columns, you stripe them again.

```
var isGray = false;
$("tr td").each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).is(".P"))
        isGray = !isGray
    else if (isGray)
        $(element).addClass("gray")
})
```

Here is a sample jsFiddle - just click to unhide - http://jsfiddle.net/wz4au7wq/